How to repair broken systemd-resolved.service on server 20.04
After applying apt updates I can no longer resolve dns names I am a novice and have spent days trying to find some insight on how to fix this, I can not replace any broken dpkg files as apt update can't resolve the repository names nor can I figure out which installed dpkg to try and reconfigure. all of the solutions on the web all reference something unusable to me since I cannot resolve anything.
  UNIT                                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● cups.path                            loaded failed failed CUPS Scheduler
● cups-browsed.service                 loaded failed failed Make remote CUPS printers available locally
● fwupd-refresh.service                loaded failed failed Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
● systemd-networkd-wait-online.service loaded failed failed Wait for Network to be Configured
● systemd-resolved.service             loaded failed failed Network Name Resolution
● whoopsie.service                     loaded failed failed crash report submission daemon
● cups.socket                          loaded failed failed CUPS Scheduler

I think this is my biggest problem, and I would like to manually reinstall the underlying service, however I do not know what that is
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2024-09-21 23:07:04 CDT; 16h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 10175 (code=dumped, signal=BUS)

Sep 21 23:07:04 regul-1 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 21 23:07:04 regul-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Sep 21 23:07:04 regul-1 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 21 23:07:04 regul-1 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Sep 21 23:07:04 regul-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.

APT could be broken, so manually reinstalling it to rule out, I still thinks root cause is with systemd-resolved.service and I have no idea how to repair it but still looking, and web searches have turned up nothing yet.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Looking for whatever will help me resolve the issue, not really too picky at this point in whatever form that come in

Fast = Test network hardware using a LiveUSB. If the LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment can access the network, then backup and reinstall. This means putting a screen/keyboard on your server, still fastest way.

Learning = Review your startup syslog/journal for clues why the network stack fails. Also look for a possible NM/systemd/netplan conflict, as looks like you have NetworkManager installed on a server.

If you learn something, edit your question to refine what you are asking. Comments are not intended for conversation.
